# portfolio site - about this site section - is it safe to post some code

Tags: php, security

I am re-bulding my portfolio site using Underscores theme. I have an about page with the section "About this site". Since I plan to apply for web dev jobs in the near future, I think its a good idea to document my learning process using my site.

Question:  I plan to mention in the "About this site" section that current version of the site is built using WordPress Underscores theme and also post some HTML and CSS to give more detail how it was built. From WP security standpoint how safe it is to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's unlikely that telling people the site was built with Underscores, or offering snippets of HTML or CSS, would present a security risk. If you said you were using a particular version of a particular theme that has security vulnerabilities, that could be a tipoff, but it's likely a bot searching for known vulnerabilities would already be able to view your HTML source and recognize that it had found a site with a vulnerable theme. So, really theme security lies more in making sure that whatever you use or build out doesn't have a bunch of loopholes - there's not a lot of need to keep it secret.

Similarly, HTML and CSS are going to be downloaded to every user and bot's browser anyway. They typically don't contain anything that puts you at more risk. CSS in particular isn't going to be a security risk, and HTML only would be if you have something stored in the source code that others shouldn't see. Like, for example, a poorly-coded site that includes personally identifiable information about users, like their social security numbers or a phone number. It's PHP and JS where loopholes are more likely to be found and exploited.

Comment: thank you for the prompt reply. Based on your answer its not a good idea to post any php code from my site when I want to show how it was built? Say which wp templates I used, some php code from those etc...

Comment: PHP snippet sharing shouldn't be a problem either, as long as you've made sure to have some basic protections in place - like keeping WP Core, themes, and plugins all up to date, using a security plugin, not using insecure passwords, those sorts of things. If the PHP you're sharing would tell the world the names of your database tables or anything site-specific like that, that's where it could become a bit risky. But sharing common functionality is usually fine.